# Return display property via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element with display property set to none.  I want to use javascript to return this display property.  The code I'm using returns nothing or NULL when it should return "none".  This is the code i'm using:

element CSS

```
.element
{
display:none;
}
```

javascript

```
function get_display_status()
{


    var element = document.getElementById('elementID');
    var status = element.style.display;

    document.write(status);
}
```

Result: Current status: ""

Image : http://gyazo.com/f662fd257602e973ca329a25314fb6ab

Any workarounds to this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're getting is the elements inline style, what you want is its computed style, try

```
var status =  document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null).display;
```

Comment: Works 100%.  Will select your answer, what exactly is the elements inline style?

Comment: That's when the element has a style attribute or you set the style like element. style.property